# Strange program crash

Tags: c++, crash, operator-overloading

I'm trying to implement a String class for an excercise. Here is my all code: (you don't need to read it all) :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


// ******************************* String ************************
class String {
    private:
        char* char_arr;

        int strlen(const char* str) {
            int length;
            for(length=0;*(str+length)!='\0';length++);
            return length;
        }


        void strCopy(const char* str1, char* str2) {
            int length = strlen(str1);
            for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
                str2[i] = str1[i];                      
        }


    public:
        // --- Constructor ---
        String(const char* str) {
            int length = strlen(str);           
            char_arr = new char[strlen(str)+1];         
            char_arr[length] = '\0';
            strCopy(str,char_arr);
        }


        // --- size Constructor ---
        explicit String(int size) {
            char_arr = new char[size+1];
            char_arr[size+1] = '\0';
        }   



        // --- Destructor ---
        ~String() {
            delete char_arr;
        }




        // --- Copy Constructor ---
        String(const String& rhs) {
            char_arr = new char[strlen(rhs.char_arr)+1];
            strCopy(rhs.char_arr,char_arr);
        }



        // --- copy-assignment Constructor
        const String& operator=(const String& rhs) {
            delete char_arr;

            char_arr = new char[strlen(rhs.char_arr)+1];
            strCopy(rhs.char_arr,char_arr);         
        }



        // --- operator== ---
        bool operator==(const String& rhs) {
            int this_length = strlen(char_arr);
            int rhs_length = strlen(rhs.char_arr);
            if(this_length==rhs_length) {
                bool return_value = true;
                for(int i=0;i<this_length;i++) {
                    if(char_arr[i]!=rhs.char_arr[i]) {
                        return_value = false;
                        break;
                    }                   
                }

                return return_value;                    
            }

            return false;
        }



        // --- operator+ ---
        String operator+(const String& rhs) {
            int this_length = strlen(char_arr);
            int rhs_length = strlen(rhs.char_arr);

            String new_str(this_length+rhs_length);
            strCopy(char_arr,new_str.char_arr);

            for(int i=0;i<rhs_length;i++) {
                new_str.char_arr[i+this_length] = rhs.char_arr[i];
            }

            new_str.char_arr[this_length+rhs_length] = '\0';
            return new_str;
        }


        // --- print ---
        void print() {
            cout << char_arr;
        }   
};




// ~~~~~~~ main ~~~~~~~~~
int main() {
    String s = "This is";
    String s1 = " My Name";
    String s2 = s+s1;
    s1.print();



    return 0;
}
```

The problem is in the operator+ overloading. If you look at the main function and change the values of s and s1, the program sometimes will crash and sometimes it won't. any ideas why it's happens?

Comment: `delete char_arr;` should be `delete[] char_arr;`

Comment: Are you able to be more specific about the conditions which cause the crash? Does it appear to be random? Are there certain string combinations which cause it? Is it just a problem when an empty string  is passed? Thanks

Comment: @ForEveR If I want to delete a class pointer, do I need to delete[] or it used only for arrays?

Comment: You must `delete[]` pointers allocated with `new[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strCopy does not copy the trailing zero byte. While there is nothing woring with it, it is somewhat counterintuitive.

Your copy constructor uses the above strCopy() and does not add zero byte too, leaving copied string unterminated. The same applies to assignment operator.

Your concatenation operator dos not allocate enough room for trailing zero byte (but appends it). The program crashes because zero byte is placed after the allocated memory block.

Comment: if I allocate a char array of length 5. the arr[4] is automaticly became '\0'? or I need to set it manually?

Comment: Why do you call strlength so much? isn't it easier to just have a length field in your string class?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the only problem, but you need to return `*this` in your `const String& operator=(const String& rhs)`. Do enable warnings in the compiler, and it should tell you "reaching end of function without return".